# Laravel - Get Collection of all data coming from Polymorphic relations

Tags: laravel, polymorphism

I would like to get all data (row results) from Polymorphic relation inside a single Collection of items

Here is the scenario:

```
matches table
--id

match_details_pivot table
--id
--match_id_fk   # a foreign key on match.id table
--details_id    # polymorphic relation model id
--details_type  # polymorphic relation model

match_details_football table
--id
--match_details_id_fk
```

The relationship is as follows:

```
Match -> hasOne MatchDetailsPivot -> hasMany MatchDetailsFootball
```

Laravel Models:

```
class Match extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'matches';

    public function details()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(MatchDetails::class, 'match_id_fk');
    }
}

class MatchDetailsPivot extends Model
{
    const MORPH_ID      =   'details_id';
    const MORPH_COLUMN  =   'details_type';

    protected $table = 'match_details_pivot';

    public function match()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Match::class, 'id', 'match_id_fk');
    }

    public function matchData()
    {
        return $this->morphTo('matchData', self::MORPH_COLUMN, self::MORPH_ID);
    }
}

class MatchDetailsFootball extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'match_details_football';

    public function matchDetails()
    {
        return $this->morphMany(MatchDetailsPivot::class, 'matchData');
    }
}
```

Example scenario:

- *Matches* table has **1** record with ID = **50**
- *Match_details_pivot* table contains **1** record with ID 12, with *foreign id* pointing to matches table, which is id **50**.
- *Match_details_pivot* table also has a polymorphic relation to load MatchDetailsFootball model with ID = **15**
- *Match_Details_Football* table has **2** records with ID **15** and **16**, and both of them have a foreign key reference pointing to a pivot table, which is id **12**

Table record example from above scenario:

```
matches
id    
50

match_details_pivot
id    match_id_fk    details_id    details_type
12    50             15            MatchDetailsFootball


match_details_football
id    match_details_id_fk    score    team
15    12                     5        Manchester
16    12                     5        Arsenal
```

**A Problem:** polymorphic relation within the pivot table, defaults to the ID column of a polymorphic table to load (match_details_football.id), however, I need it to point to a different foreign id column (match_details_football.match_details_id_fk).

Getting records:

```
$test = Match::with('details')->with('details.matchData')->where('matches.id', 50)->get();
```

This will return a single Match collection, with a single MatchDetailsPivot relation and a single MatchDetailsFootball relation.

I need it to return all MatchDetailsFootball relations.

How can this be achieved in Laravel?

Comment: Take a look at polymorphic many-to-many relationships: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many-polymorphic-relations

Comment: I think I found the solution to my problem.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33370264/laravel-many-to-one-polymorphic-relationship
Essential what I have is exactly the same as described in the link above.
As opposed to One-to-Many, what I need is Many-to-One.
Thanks for the suggestion though.